# How to change installation region

Tags: starcraft-2, region-lock

I have two starcraft accounts on different regions - one on NA server and another on EU. Right now I have the NA client installed, which means I can only log into the NA battle.net.

What is the best solution for me to be able to play on my EU account? My only 2 options seem ridiculously heavy:

1. Uninstall / reinstall
2. Use a different computer (or dual boot or something; I assume virtual machine isn't going to work)

I have read threads about people just swapping the `Core.SC2Mod\Base.SC2Data` file, but all references to that technique appear to be many months old, and I am wondering especially *how the pros do it*. I assume they must switch servers frequently, and they are probably also sensitive to Blizzard's ToS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might sound a bit trivial, but did you try installing the N.A client and E.U client on different folders?

Personally I play League of Legends on N.A and E.U servers as well, and I got them installed on 2 different folders with 2 different desktop launch Icons and they work OK.

According to: [StarCraft II EU and NA on same MACHINE ?](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=188900) apparently the split-up folders solution work, however you might want to give a try to: [SC2 Client Relocalization](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=139082)

Comment: Trying now; seems promising so far. I was annoyed at the installer audio until I realized the like 3x3 pixel button to disable it. Phew! Stay tuned...

Comment: Indeed it is as simple as that. I just installed to `c:\program files\sc2EU` and now I can play either quite easily, no scripts, no hacks. Just 2 different shortcuts on my desktop. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked! and you are welcome =]

Answer (score 1):

I not tested it but try to create another account in windows and install EU client. So you'll just need to log-in under another user to have another environment for game.